# Save creation of DecimalFormat with local and Rounding Mode

Tags: java, findbugs

I want create an instance of an NumberFormater with local (german) and rounding mode (Half Down) without cast and without any may unsave method or cast.

Up to now I was doing

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```

But then Findbugs nag:

> DMI_UNSUPPORTED_METHOD
>
> Call to unsupported method java.text.NumberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode) in new Demo()
>
> All targets of this method invocation throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

Is there any other way to create such an instance without warning, than cast NumberFormat to Decimal Format or Disable this warning?

Comment: Why don't you use `DecimalFormat` instead, since that's what `getInstance(...)` would return anyways?

Comment: @Thomas - I did not find a way to create a DecimalFormat with an given local. - May I have overlooked something?

Comment: You're right, `NumberFormat.getInstance(locale)` uses some internal classes like `LocaleData` and `DecimalFormatSymbols` to get the parameters for the `DecimalFormat` and I'd not recommend messing with these yourself. - However, if you use a certain fixed locale (like GERMAN in your case), you might also provide the format string yourself.

Comment: This findbugs warning seems wrong to me.  Not all targets throw an UnsupportedOperationException.